# $SL_2(q)$ is isomorphic to $SU_2(q)$.

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, finite-fields, group-isomorphism

I have seen at least twice in literature that $SU_2(q) \cong SL_2(q)$. How can we actually prove that these two groups are isomorphic? The problem I see is that $SL_2(q)$ is defined over $\mathbb{F}_q$ while $SU_2(q)$ is defined over $\mathbb{F}_{q^2}$.

Comment: I have no idea what should be called $SU_2(q)$, as there is no complex structure on $\mathbb{F}_q$.

Comment: @cjackal chose any sesquilinear form on $\Bbb F_{q^2}$.